# Actionscript 3.0 Disable navigateToURL

Tags: security, actionscript

A web game I play on that allows user uploaded content has been having a lot of issues with people using the navigateToURL function to send players to random websites. I was curious if there was a way to disable this function using Actionscript 2 or 3. I have seen a way to do it using the HTML embed but I do not have administrative access to the website.

Comment: describe the exploit a bit more: do the users have to click to be redirected? or is code created by the end user causing this. What is the type of file the user content comes in?>

Comment: Ok, so the website allows users to upload images or .swf files onto it. These uploads can then be put into rooms as furniture, "toys", pets, or avatars. The game itself is flash based so the rooms are a flash client. The uploaded .swfs can run Actionscript which allows people to simply make something run the navigateToURL on all clients viewing the room. Most targets are blocked but there's a few that bypass it so I need a way to input a .swf into a room that simply prevents the function from working.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research, I have come up with a solid answer: 
You should use a combination of PHP and an executable called swfdump on the server side to validate the user uploaded content.

swfdump is an exe file located in the bin folder of the Flex SDK. You can run it from PHP using exec. 
It will read the bytecode of the swf and produce a report. From that you can easily locate which files contain navigateToURL() and reject the files.

I tested a file of my own using swfdump -abc -out myfilereport.swfx myfile.swf
and in that output I found this:

```
        findpropstrict  flash.net:navigateToURL
        findpropstrict  flash.net:URLRequest
        pushstring      "http://www.plasticsturgeon.com"
        constructprop   flash.net:URLRequest (1)
        callproperty    flash.net:navigateToURL (1)
```

The url I was using was "http://www.plasticsturgeon.com". But it would be far easuer to just eliminate any swf that includes flash.net.navigateToURL. Once you identify tha is present you can generate an error notice to your end user.

So using this method you can find and reject any swf that is using navigate to URL. You could even create a batch to run and invalidate any existing assert with this problem.

More information about using bytecode:
http://code.google.com/p/redtamarin/wiki/ABC

And about decompiling ASbytecode:
http://dougmccune.com/flex/FOTB_Decompiling_Doug_McCune.pdf